# Leaflet map integration with a React framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I’m trying to convert my previous vanilla JavaScript files into React framework. My application has to use a map and I chose Leaflet for it. Previously, I attached the cdn of leaflet to the head of my index.html file but now I installed leaflet through npm directly into the project. Usually, the syntax to implement leaflet is const map = L.map(“map-Id”);
And I have a few hundred lines of code in my file that use JavaScript to manipulate the map. I’m now having trouble with just the first step of displaying the map on the website. I couldn’t find any solution to const map = L.map(“”) since when I tried to include my Leaflet script (useLeaflet.js), into a React file as a component, it always returns the error that whether it couldn’t recognize map or map has been initialized. Hope that you can help me with this. I’m a newbie to React so the trial took me so long.

I tried to create const map = L.map or L.Map or map or Map both in the React file or a separate thing. The error is nearly always map is not define. I don’t know what other to do since I couldn’t find much. There is the react-leaflet library but it has limited capacity in term of functionalities, functions, methods, etc. so I want to stick with leaflet library only.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import "./leaflet.js";
function LeafletMap() {
useEffect(() => {
    let container = L.DomUtil.get("map");
    if (container != null) {
      container._leaflet_id = null;
    }
    let map = L.map("mapid").setView([cenLat, cenLng], zoom);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution: "Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors",
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([-31.505, 150.09]).addTo(map);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id="mapid"></div>
);
}
export default LeafletMap;
```

I'm trying multiple variations of the above code but none works or whatsoever.

Comment: Use [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) and it will solve your problems.
And here you have my examples [react-leaflet-examples](https://tomickigrzegorz.github.io/react-leaflet-examples/#/simple-map)